# How to change response content type header of Spring @RestController

Tags: spring, content-type, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to change HttpServletResponse content Type from filter class but chnages are not reflecting.

Filter Class :

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class TestFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain arg2)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (arg1 instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) arg1;
            httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/xml");
            arg1.setContentType("application/xml");
            
            String contentType = httpServletResponse.getContentType();  
            System.out.println("contentType : "+contentType);
            
        arg2.doFilter(arg0, new HttpServletResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse) {
            @Override
            public void setContentType(final String type) {
                
            }
        });
        String contentType1 = httpServletResponse.getContentType();
        System.out.println("contentType1 : "+contentType1);
        String contentType2 = httpServletResponse.getContentType();
        System.out.println("contentType2 : "+contentType2);
    }
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @PostMapping(path="/test", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE,  
            produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public String test() {
        return "<SUCCESS></SUCCESS>";
    }
}
```

But still I am getting application/json as response content type it should be application/xml. How can I fix this ?

Response Logs :
contentType : application/xml
contentType1 : application/json
contentType2 : application/json

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify the content type using `ResponseEntity`:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {
    
    @PostMapping(path="/test", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
                .body("<SUCCESS></SUCCESS>");
    }
}
```